# Why is there no plugin detection technique (like navigator.plugins) in PHP?

Tags: detection

Why is there no plugin detection technique (like `navigator.plugins`) in PHP? Why it is not implemented? It would be great! Any thoughts on how to do it?

Edit: Like in `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`

Answer (score 5):

For browser information in general, the server only know what the client explicitly tells it, which is typically only a user agent string.  You'll have to setup an AJAX method to send any other data you may want the server to know about on a per-session basis

For PHP extensions, you can use `get_loaded_extensions()`.  From the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-loaded-extensions.php):

Example #1 get_loaded_extensions() Example

```
<?php
print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
?>
```

The above example will output something similar to:

```
Array
(
   [0] => xml
   [1] => wddx
   [2] => standard
   [3] => session
   [4] => posix
   [5] => pgsql
   [6] => pcre
   [7] => gd
   [8] => ftp
   [9] => db
   [10] => calendar
   [11] => bcmath
)
```

Comment: so these are server extensions. more elegant than php_info. +1

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to detect php-plugins or browser-plugins?

browser-plugins:

send `navigator.plugins` to one of your php scripts via an ajax call.

php-plugins:

evaluate `php_info()` for the wanted plugin (maybe there is a more straightforward way?)